# How do I match a response to a request if there are multiple requests made with promises?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, axios

I'm making multiple requests with promises, getting historical pricing data for an array of stocks.

Because the responses may not come back in the same sequential order, I need a way to know which response corresponds to which request. The responses come back with no identifying information.

Here's what one response looks like:

```
{
    history: {
        day: {
            date: '1996-01-02', 
            open: 61.4063,
            close: 63.6719,
            high: 63.6875,
            low: 59.6406,
            volume: 10507600
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

And here's my request:

```
var promises = [];
var symbols = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'FB', 'NVDA'];

symbols.forEach(function(symbol) {
  promises.push(axios.get('https://sandbox.tradier.com/v1/markets/history', {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tradierACCESSTOKEN
    },
    params: {
      symbol: symbol,
      interval: 'daily',
      start: '2012-01-01'
    }
  }));
});

axios.all(promises)
  .then(function(responses) { 
    responses.forEach(function(response) {
      var data = response.data;
      // how do i know which response corresponds with the requested stock?
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: What is `axios` in `axios.all()`?

Comment: I can't get it why many people make their life hard and try to use promises on lists. Better use `async` it is much more easier and the code is much more readable. Try `async.map`. http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map

Comment: @FrankRoth How would that be easier? You still have a collection, you still have the `iteratee`, and you still have a result handler. You still need essentially the same code, you just call it differently. And `async.map` does not even use promises, hello callback-hell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> axios depends on a native ES6 Promise implementation

([source](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#promises))

In the case of fulfillment, `response` contains an array of individual responses in the same order as you added them to `Promise.all`. This means that `response[0]` will always be the response of the request for `'MSFT'`.

> If all of the passed-in promises fulfill, Promise.all is fulfilled with an array of the values from the passed-in promises, in the same order as defined in the iterable.

([MDN: `Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all))

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a non-promise approuch. The http.get is just a pseude implementation:

```
var request = function(symbol, cb){
    http.get('https://sandbox.tradier.com/v1/markets/history', {
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json', Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tradierACCESSTOKEN },
        params: { symbol: symbol, interval: 'daily', start: '2012-01-01' }
    }, cb);
};

var done = function(err, results){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(results));  // results => array same order as input
}

async.map(['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'FB', 'NVDA'], request, done);
```

Not sure  where the callback hell is here.